# Ubuntu 20 Kernel panic after moving and resizing root partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, kernel

My system was running smoothly until my root partition started running out of space. So I decided to try to resize it, unfortunately I needed to move it to the left as well. It seems that the process went well. gparted warned me that maybe I woundn't be able to boot anymore, I thought I would just need to repair grub. Since then I got a kernel panic message when trying to boot. I did repaired grub with boot-repair, but nothing changed.

[Kernel Panic Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkUc1.jpg)

What I find curious is that I can boot with the older kernel Linux 5.4.0-33, but I got the kernel panic message when booting with the 5.4.0-39 or 5.4.0-37. I already tried to reinstall kernel 37 and I was able to boot normally for a while, but then the problem reapeared. Also, for discarting the posibility of bad sectors on my disk, even though it is new, I checked my whole disk with badblocks tool and all seems to be right.

Anybody can help me ?

Comment: Do you get the Grub screen when you boot.  If so then boot with the oldest kernel you have.  If that fails then drop to recovery, enable networking and then update and upgrade and then sudo dpkg --configure -a.  and or sudo apt install -f

Comment: Oh alright, I tried to reinstall the kernell, but I'll try that and tell you, thank you !

Comment: Hey, it seems to be working now ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Do you get the Grub screen when you boot. If so then boot with the oldest kernel you have. If that fails then drop to recovery, enable networking and then update and upgrade and then

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a.
```

and or

```
sudo apt install -f
```